# Why SQL query returns table data when using backtick in select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was solving a CTF challange which is using Javascript objects used in SQL query but I can't quite understand why it works. Here are the commands I used.

```
mysql> select * from myTable;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | first      | second      |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | first_data | second_data |
|  2 | third_data | fourth_data |
+----+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from myTable where first = `second` = 'anyString';
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | first      | second      |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | first_data | second_data |
|  2 | third_data | fourth_data |
+----+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from myTable where first = `first` = 'anyString';
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is not doing what you expect:

```
first = `second` = 'anyString'
```

This is parsed as:

```
first = (`second` = 'anyString')
```

(I realize this might technically be:  `(first = second) = 'anyString'`, but that doesn't change the explanation.)

Which in general would be:

```
first = false
```

Because MySQL treats booleans as numbers, this is equivalent to:

```
first = 0
```

And `first` is implicitly converted to a number.  The implicit conversion converts leading digits.  And if there are none, it is `0`.  So, this becomes:

```
0 = 0
```

Voila!  All the data is returned.